# build scheduled during frame after changing tab in tab bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I apologize if the title of this question might be slightly incorrect, however I was unsure what to title it and it is mostly correct.

I am working on a tabbed navigation system similar to that of a typical web browser. I have most of the actual tabbed system working, thanks to Yuriy Luchaninov's answer in [How to create a dynamic TabBarView/ Render a new Tab with a function in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036546/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tabbarview-render-a-new-tab-with-a-function-in-flutter) and a few custom changes. However, one issue I am unsure how to solve is that I need a 'create new tab button' that is embedded into the tab bar itself. Having added one, [image: tabbar with add button] I use riverpod to manage the state of the list of tabs. I'm using a StateNotifierProvider and a custom notifier. I don't *think* much of this has anything to do with my primary question, but I think it is valuable context to help get to the root of my issue.

Namely, I am getting an error when I change which tab I have currently selected - [image: build scheduled during frame error]

This error appears somewhat inconsistently, and does not seem to have a clear cause. I had a previous implementation that had seemingly the same (or worse) error which did not use riverpod but instead a built-in List to serve as the tab bar state.

The exception is thrown when I add a tab while the currently open tab is not the final index in the tab bar, and then attempt to open the new tab. The error is not thrown if the tab is opened while the currently selected tab was the previous end of the tab bar.

Here's an example of it working properly: [image: gif of no error]

Here's an example of it breaking: [image: gif of error]

Now, to get to the actual issue - which I am completely lost on. I am not sure why the specific index that is called would be an issue causing it to break, and especially not why the exception that is called is from the animation library. In fact, I have attempted to disable all animations in the tab bar by setting `animationDuration: Duration.zero)` in the TabControllers used (not as a method to fix the issue, but because I don't want them for my solution).

Here is the custom tab widget that is mostly the same as the one found in the question linked above.

```dart
class CustomTabView extends StatefulWidget {
  final int itemCount;
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder tabBuilder;
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder pageBuilder;
  final Widget? stub;
  final ValueChanged<int>? onPositionChange;
  final int? initPosition;
  final void Function(int tabIndexPosition)? onMiddleMouseButtonTapUp;
  final VoidCallback onAddPressed;

  /// referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036546/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tabbarview-render-a-new-tab-with-a-function-in-flutter
  /// with edits for our usage
  const CustomTabView({
    required this.itemCount,
    required this.tabBuilder,
    required this.pageBuilder,
    this.stub,
    this.onPositionChange,
    this.initPosition,
    this.onMiddleMouseButtonTapUp,
    required this.onAddPressed,
  });

  @override
  _CustomTabViewState createState() => _CustomTabViewState();
}

class _CustomTabViewState extends State<CustomTabView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController controller;
  late int _currentCount;
  late int _currentPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentPosition = widget.initPosition ?? 0;
    controller = TabController(
        length: widget.itemCount,
        vsync: this,
        initialIndex: _currentPosition,
        animationDuration: Duration.zero);
    controller.addListener(onPositionChange);
    _currentCount = widget.itemCount;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CustomTabView oldWidget) {
    if (_currentCount != widget.itemCount) {
      controller.removeListener(onPositionChange);
      controller.dispose();

      if (widget.initPosition != null) {
        _currentPosition = widget.initPosition!;
      }

      if (_currentPosition > widget.itemCount - 1) {
        _currentPosition = widget.itemCount - 1;
        _currentPosition = _currentPosition < 0 ? 0 : _currentPosition;
        if (widget.onPositionChange is ValueChanged<int>) {
          WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            if (mounted) {
              widget.onPositionChange!(_currentPosition);
            }
          });
        }
      }

      _currentCount = widget.itemCount;
      setState(() {
        controller = TabController(
            length: widget.itemCount,
            vsync: this,
            initialIndex: _currentPosition,
            animationDuration: Duration.zero);
        controller.addListener(onPositionChange);
      });
    } else if (widget.initPosition != null) {
      controller.animateTo(widget.initPosition!);
    }

    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(onPositionChange);
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.itemCount < 1) return widget.stub ?? Container();

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTertiaryTapUp: (details) {
                  if (widget.onMiddleMouseButtonTapUp != null) {
                    widget.onMiddleMouseButtonTapUp!(_currentPosition);
                  }
                },
                child: TabBar(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  isScrollable: true,
                  controller: controller,
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(1),
                  ),
                  tabs: List.generate(
                    widget.itemCount,
                    (index) => widget.tabBuilder(context, index),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: widget.onAddPressed,
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                minimumSize: Size.zero,
                tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: controller,
            children: List.generate(
              widget.itemCount,
              (index) => widget.pageBuilder(context, index),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  onPositionChange() {
    if (!controller.indexIsChanging) {
      _currentPosition = controller.index;
      if (widget.onPositionChange is ValueChanged<int>) {
        widget.onPositionChange!(_currentPosition);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the provider system used to add tabs:

```dart
final tabsNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<TabsNotifier, List<TabObject>>(
  (ref) => TabsNotifier(),
);

class TabsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<TabObject>> {
  TabsNotifier() : super([]);

  void addTab(TabObject tab) {
    state = [...state, tab];
  }

  void removeTabByIndex(int index) {
    List<TabObject> newState = List.from(state);
    newState.removeAt(index);
    state = newState;
  }
}
```

And here is the rest of the system:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FocusNode currentTabFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
        final tabs = ref.watch(tabsNotifierProvider);
        if (tabs.isEmpty) {
          Future.delayed(
            Duration.zero,
            () => ref.read(tabsNotifierProvider.notifier).addTab(
                TabObject(tabType: TabOjectType.ENTRY, tabName: 'default')),
          );
        }
        return CustomTabView(
            onAddPressed: () {
              Future.delayed(
                  Duration.zero,
                  () => ref
                      .read(tabsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                      .addTab(TabObject(tabType: TabOjectType.EMPTY)));
            },
            onMiddleMouseButtonTapUp: (index) {
              Future.delayed(
                  Duration.zero,
                  (() => ref
                      .read(tabsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                      .removeTabByIndex(index)));
            },
            itemCount: tabs.length,
            tabBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (tabs[index].tabType == TabOjectType.CREATE_NEW) {
                return tabs[index].prefixImagePlaceholder;
              } else {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints:
                            const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 25, maxWidth: 25),
                        child: tabs[index].prefixImagePlaceholder),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                      child: Text('${tabs[index].tabName}'),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          minimumSize: Size.zero,
                          tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                          shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (index != 0) {
                            setState(() {
                              tabs.removeAt(index);
                            });
                          } else {
                            // TODO close whole project
                          }
                        },
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ))
                  ],
                );
              }
            },
            pageBuilder: (context, index) {
              return RawKeyboardListener(
                focusNode: currentTabFocusNode,
                onKey: (value) {
                  if (value is RawKeyDownEvent) {
                    if (value.isControlPressed &&
                        value.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.keyW) {
                      print('ctrl w pressed');
                      setState(() {
                        tabs.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('tab $index'),
                ),
              );
            });
      }),
    );
  }
}

enum TabOjectType {
  CREATE_NEW,
  ENTRY,
  HIGH_LEVEL,
  HOME,
  CURRENT_PROJECT,
  EMPTY,
}

class TabObject {
  static TabObject createNew() {
    return TabObject(
        tabType: TabOjectType.CREATE_NEW,
        prefixImagePlaceholder: Icon(Icons.add),
        tabName: '');
  }

  Widget prefixImagePlaceholder;

  /// this is the optionally provided actual object which the tab is referencing -- such as the entry of an entry page or its id
  dynamic object;
  String? tabName;
  TabOjectType tabType;

  TabObject(
      {required this.tabType,
      this.prefixImagePlaceholder = const Placeholder(
        fallbackHeight: 10,
        fallbackWidth: 10,
      ),
      this.object,
      this.tabName});
}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

--- EDIT ---

Here is some additional information on the error. This is the error stack and the called exception. I'm not sure why it seems that the animation controller is what is calling the exception.

```
Exception caught by animation library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while notifying listeners for AnimationController:
Build scheduled during frame.

While the widget tree was being built, laid out, and painted, a new frame was scheduled to rebuild the widget tree.

This might be because setState() was called from a layout or paint callback. If a change is needed to the widget tree, it should be applied as the tree is being built. Scheduling a change for the subsequent frame instead results in an interface that lags behind by one frame. If this was done to make your build dependent on a size measured at layout time, consider using a LayoutBuilder, CustomSingleChildLayout, or CustomMultiChildLayout. If, on the other hand, the one frame delay is the desired effect, for example because this is an animation, consider scheduling the frame in a post-frame callback using SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback or using an AnimationController to trigger the animation.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      WidgetsBinding._handleBuildScheduled.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:747
#1      WidgetsBinding._handleBuildScheduled
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:770
#2      BuildOwner.scheduleBuildFor
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2485
#3      Element.markNeedsBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4443
#4      State.setState
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1141
#5      _AnimatedState._handleChange
package:flutter/…/widgets/transitions.dart:128
#6      AnimationLocalListenersMixin.notifyListeners
package:flutter/…/animation/listener_helpers.dart:155
#7      AnimationController.value=
package:flutter/…/animation/animation_controller.dart:365
#8      TabController._changeIndex
package:flutter/…/material/tab_controller.dart:201
#9      TabController.index=
package:flutter/…/material/tab_controller.dart:219
#10     _TabBarViewState._handleScrollNotification
package:flutter/…/material/tabs.dart:1458
#11     NotificationListener._dispatch
package:flutter/…/widgets/notification_listener.dart:151
#12     Notification.visitAncestor
package:flutter/…/widgets/notification_listener.dart:67
#13     ViewportNotificationMixin.visitAncestor
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_notification.dart:31
#14     Element.visitAncestorElements
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4254
#15     Notification.dispatch
package:flutter/…/widgets/notification_listener.dart:83
#16     ScrollActivity.dispatchScrollEndNotification
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_activity.dart:104
#17     ScrollPosition.didEndScroll
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position.dart:907
#18     ScrollPosition.beginActivity
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position.dart:876
#19     ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.beginActivity
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:114
#20     ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.goIdle
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:129
#21     ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.goBallistic
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:148
#22     BallisticScrollActivity.applyNewDimensions
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_activity.dart:549
#23     ScrollPosition.applyNewDimensions
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position.dart:623
#24     ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.applyNewDimensions
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:104
#25     ScrollPosition.applyContentDimensions
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position.dart:553
#26     _PagePosition.applyContentDimensions
package:flutter/…/widgets/page_view.dart:473
#27     RenderViewport.performLayout
package:flutter/…/rendering/viewport.dart:1493
#28     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1731
#29     PipelineOwner.flushLayout
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:887
#30     RendererBinding.drawFrame
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:497
#31     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:883
#32     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:363
#33     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1144
#34     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1081
#35     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:995
#39     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#40     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#41     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
The AnimationController notifying listeners was: AnimationController#63a5c(▶ 3.000; paused)
```

Comment: I don't like that you setState during didUpdateWidget .... Does this problem sound similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60863229/build-scheduled-during-frame-when-height-of-widget-below-a-listview-decreases

Comment: Unfortunately the solutions presented in that question don't seem to make much difference here. I tried adding the setstate to a post frame callback, and that broke the whole application because the controller was not rebuilt when needed. 

Removing the setstate entirely doesn't seem to be an issue, however it doesn't actually fix the issue itself.

Comment: are you using riverpod/provider and which version of it?

Comment: I am using riverpod. Version ^1.0.3. I have also attempted to use a basic List for the state, and had similar issues.